# $EV(x): x \mapsto ev_x$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $M$ be Locally compact Hausdorff and $C_0(M)$ denote the space of real valued continuous functions that vanish at infinity.  My questions reads: ''Show that $EV$ is a homeomorphism onto its image $EV(X)$ equipped with the weak* topology.''

To show continuity I tried;

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $M$ converging to $x$, fix $f \in C_0(M)$. Calculate;

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}EV(x_n)f=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}ev_{x_n}f=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)=f(x)=EV(x)f$$

But this dosn't make any sense to me. I never touched the topology on $C_0(M)^*$, which would imply that $EV$ is always continuous no matter what open sets look like in $C_0(M)^*$? But isn't the whole point of the weak star topology to force the maps $ev_x$ to be continuous. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should edit your question: replace "LCH" by "locally compact Hausdorff", replace $EV(x)$ by $EV$.

Comment: Moreover, keep in mind that in general topological spaces, showing sequential continuity is usually not enough to show continuity.

Comment: @Plop This is most upsetting. I will try to do the proof with open sets and edit

Comment: Any hints on how to proceed? General open sets in w, and w* topologies are very mysterious to me

Comment: @Muselive, when it comes to open sets in weak topologies, the key is to use "basic open sets" as you would use open balls in a metric space.  (A basic open set is one of the form $\cap_{i = 1}^{L} \{f \, \mid \, |f(x_{i}) - f_{i}(x_{i})| < \epsilon\}$, where $\epsilon > 0$, $x_{1},\dots,x_{L}$ are in $C_{0}(M)$, and $f_{1},\dots,f_{L} \in C_{0}(M)^{*}$.)

Answer (score 1):

You say that you did not touch the topology of $C_0(M)^*$. You did!

Let's recall. Assume that $X$ is a topological vector space. Then we define the topological dual $X^*$ as $\{\varphi:X\to\mathbb{K}\vert\;\;  \varphi \text{ is continuous on }X\}$.
and we endow $X^*$ with the weak-star topology; this is a locally convex topology on $X^*$ that is produced by the family of seminorms $\{p_x\}_{x\in X}$, where $p_x(\varphi)=|\varphi(x)|$. It is easily verified that a net $\{\varphi_i\}\subset X^*$ converges to $\varphi\in X^*$ with respect to the weak-star topology if and only if for all $x\in X$ we have that $\varphi_i(x)\to\varphi(x)$ (and this happens of course in $\mathbb{K}$ and its standard topology).

Now you have a map $\text{ev}:M\to C_0(M)^*$ (where $M$ has its topology and $C_0(M)^*$ has the weak star topology coming from being the dual of $C_0(M)$) and you are showing that $\text{ev}$ is continuous with respect to the topologies just mentioned. So, you need to show that, if $\{x_i\}\subset M$ is a net in $M$ converging to $x\in M$, then $\text{ev}(x_i)$ converges to $\text{ev}(x)$ in $C_0(M)^*$ in the weak-star topology. As we explained, we have to show that for every element $f\in C_0(M)$, we have that $\text{ev}(x_i)(f)\xrightarrow[i\in I]{}\text{ev}(x)(f)$ (this happens in $\mathbb{K}$). This is precisely what you did, using of course the fact that when $f\in C_0(M)$, then $f$ is continuous as a function $f:M\to\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: "or a LCH space if you prefer"  What is the topological dual of a LCH space?  I guess "or a Banach space if you prefer" would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @PeterMorfe a lch space is a tvs where the topology is induced by a family of seminorms, that's all i mean

Comment: Now that makes sense.  I think the OP was using LCH as "locally compact Hausdorff."

Comment: @PeterMorfe yes, exactly. These are equivalent definitions to my knowledge (given that the seminorms are a separating family)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by equivalent; it seems like we're on different wavelengths.  There are locally compact Hausdorff topological spaces, which need not have any linear structure (and I presume this is what $M$ is in the question), and locally convex TVS, which aren't locally compact in interesting cases.  What is equivalent to what?  My comment was to point out that the use of LCH in your answer was not consistent with the OP's and hence confusing.

Comment: @PeterMorfe Woops! I mean't locally CONVEX, I misread. You are totally right, I will write it explicitly. Thanks and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I did not know there was ambiguity in the abbreviation LCH, I edited to be more clear.  I did indeed mean Locally compact HD, which I think makes my proof invalid based on the of comments-correct?

Comment: As we have no reason to think M is sequentially closed.

Comment: @Muselive well, if you just replace sequences by nets then your proof is totally fine. The question is, are you familiar with nets?